# MySQL in Visual Studio 2012 for C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I am creating an application using Visual Studio with C and I would like to link it to mysql.
I have the problem that I don't see the wizard in the database explorer:

[image]

and I am not able to add references to mysql

[image]

I have downloaded the MySQL Connector/C++ 1.1.3.. Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you check the various related questions to the right of this post?

Comment: yep i did.. i can not make it work..